# How to make a windows installer for Monogame/F# game?

Tags: monogame, windows, installer

Alright, I have several questions that I haven't been able to find answers to yet. It looks like WiX and Inno Setup are pretty standard solutions for making the installer. WiX looks pretty intimidating and I got lost reading the tutorial on their site, so I'll probably use Inno Setup.

My questions:

- What are the dependencies for Monogame that I need to install? I couldn't find any official documentation on this. I found a few forums posts where people said you'll likely need DX 11 and .NET 4.0. My visual studio project says .NET 4.5, so I'm guessing that's actually the one I need?
- What things in my output directory need to be installed? I've got some .XML, .pdb, and .config files and I doubt I should be including them? Does MS have documentation on this?
- Are there any tools to help me make sure I've got everything? Maybe some Visual Studio automation for doing this stuff? It looks like there is a WiX template for XNA, but I have no idea if I can safely use that with monogame.
- Do I need a separate windows computer (including license) just to test the install? Or can I make a VM and use like a trial version of windows? It looks like windows 10 has a trial mode.
- Additional guides, tutorials, or documentation I should be reading?

Thanks!

Here are the files in my output directory for the **release** build (do I need all these?):

- font.xnb
- FSharp.Core.dll
- FSharp.Core.xml
- MonoGame.Framework.dll
- MonoGame.Framework.xml
- NVorbis.dll
- OpenTK.dll
- Pong.exe
- Pong.exe.config
- Pong.pdb
- Pong.XML
- pop.xnb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `OpenTK.dll` you are using the OpenGL version of MonoGame. Therefore you don't have to care about DirectX, but you need to include and silently run the [OpenAL installer](http://openal.org/downloads/) during the installation. You should also link to the [.NET 4.5+ installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Windows Vista/7 users.

The XML files contain documentation comments and the PDB contains debug information. You should not include them. I'm not sure if the .config file is necessary either, it depends on your project.

Inno Setup is a good choice in my opinion. For such a small project, attempting to automate things any further might be an overkill. I'm not a lawyer, but a VM would be just perfect for testing the install.